# Why is blogger showing an image of gears before the page loads?

Tags: javascript, css, usability

Ie., follow this link:
http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2012/04/toward-simpler-more-beautiful-google.html

Notice, you'll see some spinning gears, and then the page loads.

Does this serve some usability or performance purpose that I don't quite understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because some of the UI parts of Google's [gwt](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/) library that Google uses to build a lot of their online sites work better if the library allowed to take over the whole screen. So while gwt is initializing, that is displayed to give the user a decent experience.

I personally don't care for this design. I think if you can get the UI to come up without that delay, that would be preferable. But obviously if it is going to take awhile to load, putting a "loading" indicator on the screen is better than *not* putting up the indicator.

Answer (score 0):

It is purely user experience oriented. There is always a time lag between the moment you enter any web address in your address bar and the server returns the web page. Instead of showing nothing in this time frame, what they have done is to show a small gif.